# Invalid data for ipc_version in line 10 32-33

Tags: csv, sas

When I import a CSV file into SAS by following codes,

```
data SASDATA.IPClassification ;
infile 'R:/Li/PATSTAT/IPClassification.csv' DLM = ',' DSD missover lrecl = 32767 firstobs = 2 ;
input appln_id :29. ipc_class_symbol &:$29. ipc_class_level :$29. ipc_version :MMDDYY10. ipc_value :$29. ipc_position :$29. ipc_gener_auth :$29. ;
run ;
```

The Output DATA shows all variables except appln_id are recorded in volume of ipc_class_symbol. The records in the log shows as below,

```
NOTE: The infile 'R:/Li/PATSTAT/IPClassification.csv' is:
   Filename=R:\Li\PATSTAT\IPClassification.csv,
   RECFM=V,LRECL=32767,
   File Size (bytes)=9144764490,
   Last Modified=22Sep2017:21:09:41,
   Create Time=15Mar2018:14:50:17

 NOTE: Invalid data for ipc_version in line 10 32-33.
 RULE:     ----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5----+----6----+----7----+----8----+----9
 10        2,C07K  14/00,A,2006-01-01,I, ,EP 33
 appln_id=2 ipc_class_symbol=C07K  14/00,A,2006-01-01,I ipc_class_level=  ipc_version=. ipc_value= 
 ipc_position=  ipc_gener_auth=  _ERROR_=1 _N_=9
 NOTE: Invalid data for ipc_version in line 14 32-33.
 14        2,C07K  16/26,A,2006-01-01,I, ,EP 33
 appln_id=2 ipc_class_symbol=C07K  16/26,A,2006-01-01,I ipc_class_level=  ipc_version=. ipc_value= 
 ipc_position=  ipc_gener_auth=  _ERROR_=1 _N_=13
```

I think one of problem is ipc_class_symbol.
It is the 'IPC classification symbol (IPC 8th edition) '.
Domain: Up to 15 characters (A-Z, 0-9, /, space) as allowed by IPC;

Examples:

A61K

H04Q 7/32

C07K 14/00

C07D 405/06

H01M2220/20

Note that spaces may be required on position 5-7, because the slash "/" is always on the 9th position.

The character of rest variables are
IPC_CLASS_LEVEL
Domain: 1 character: A = classification in the full IPC e.g. 'H04Q 7/32' C = classification in main groups only e.g. 'H04H 1/00' S = classification in subclasses only e. g. 'H04H'

ipc_version
Domain: Date between '2006-01-01' and current date

ipc_value
Domain: 1 character: I=Invention, N=Additional (Non-Invention)

ipc_position
Domain: 1 character: F=first, L=later. space =unidentified

ipc_gener_auth
Domain: 2 ASCII characters (A-Z), according to WIPO ST.3

What should I do for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`&:$29` is probably your problem.  `&` there is telling SAS to wait for *two consecutive* delimiters (this is one way of dealing with delimiters embedded in the data, though it is not a common one).  That's not (apparently) correct for your data, as far as I can tell.

Remove the `&` and see if it imports correctly.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: Invalid data for ipc_version in line 10 32-33.
 RULE:     ----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5----+----6----+----7----+----8----+----9
 10        2,C07K  14/00,A,**2006-01-01**,I, ,EP 33

ipc_version :**MMDDYY10.**

Your data doesn't have the format you're trying to read it in. You've specified mmddyy, but its clearly yymmdd or something along those lines.